# jTable keeps throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable, nullpointerexception

I have a rather confusing setup for a program that lets the user choose the number of rows in a table in a jDialog, input data, and returns the data in several arrays (for each column) to the main form. I thought things were going pretty smoothly up to last night, but this morning the table keeps giving me a NullPointerException error no matter what I do. I've done some research online and tested the table several times, and I don't know what's wrong.
Here's what I have: (Also, the data from the first column is ignored, it's not a mistake. My table has 7 columns.)

This is where the exception is being thrown; I'm trying to access the data of column 7.

```
public int[] getWDurabilityEV() {
    int rowCount = tbl_Units.getRowCount();
    int[] value = new int[rowCount];
    for (int i=0;i<value.length;i++) {
        value[i] = Integer.parseInt(tbl_Units.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());
    }
    return value;
}
```

This is the button click event on the main form (the other gets are exactly like my example with a different column index; the for loop at the end is an example of how I'm updating the table on my main form)

```
   private void EVButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        dialog_EV1 EV1 = new dialog_EV1(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
//setting values
        EV1.ev1_weapon = ev1_weapon;
        EV1.ev1_wstrength = ev1_wstrength;
        EV1.ev1_wrange = ev1_wrange;
        EV1.ev1_wrate = ev1_wrate;
        EV1.ev1_wdurability = ev1_wdurability;
        EV1.ev1_wportability = ev1_wportability;
        EV1.setData();
        EV1.show();
//getting values
        ev1_weapon = EV1.getWeapon();
        ev1_wstrength = EV1.getWStrengthEV();
        ev1_wrange = EV1.getWRangeEV();
        ev1_wrate = EV1.getWRateEV();
        ev1_wdurability = EV1.getWDurabilityEV();
        ev2_wportability = EV1.getWPortabilityEV();
//calcuating values and updating table
        for (int i=0;i<ev1_weapon.length;i++) {
            tbl_Units.setValueAt(ev1_weapon[i],i,1);
        }   
    }
```

And finally, the exception thrown:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at light.dialog_EV1.getWDurabilityEV(dialog_EV1.java:200)
    at light.MainGUI.EVButton1ActionPerformed(MainGUI.java:1061)
    at light.MainGUI.access$100(MainGUI.java:28)
    at light.MainGUI$2.actionPerformed(MainGUI.java:167)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6288)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6053)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4651)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:643)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:616)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:614)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:613)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Can you post line 200 of file `dialog_EV1.java`? Because thats the point where the NPE flies.

Comment: I highly suggest that you compact your question - this is a bit excessive.

Comment: @mtsz: the line is: value[i] = Integer.parseInt(tbl_Units.getValueAt(i, 6).toString());

Comment: Why does `tbl_Units` have a `String` in column 7 instead of an `int`? For which row(s) is that `String` `null`?

Comment: I was parsing the string to an int before @mKorbel's told me that I could simply do a conversion. I've changed the code as he suggested but an exception is still being thrown.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: I've solved the problem; It had to do with poor coding in my own model updating class that was setting all the values to null every time it was initiated. I should have taken a look at it more thoroughly instead of suspecting my get() methods. I may just take mKorbel's suggestion and switch to AbstractTableModel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nothing much to clear from your question, nor from code, please edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

1) create public [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) for storing data,

2) add `TableModel` to the `JTable`

3) add [ListSelectionMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection) (SINGLE_SELECTION) to the `JTable`, 
notice test

`if(selectedRow > -1)`

4) JTable knows follows [data types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), then there no reason for parsing Integer from String e.i.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I've tried to condense my question as much as possible. In reply to your suggestions:
1) What's the benefit of switching to AbstractTableModel? Could you clarify?
2) I already have added a table model to jTable.
3) I'm not sure how this will help; the exception is being thrown with the columns...
4) Thanks for the data types; I've set the data types in my table.